# Where should i store images on my content management system?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, content-management-system

I am developing a content management system and i decided to store my images on the hard drive instead on the database.

However there is a problem and here it is:

When i develop the system i am programing it on my local server and then upload it on the remote server. If the images are stored on the hard drive in the direktory of the web application they will be automatically deleted when i deploy the new version. So the question is where should i exactly store the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of choices and it depends on how much storage you need. Assuming you're using a linux server (EC2?) you should create a mount on a separate disk and give the web server process access to that disk. Mount it somewhere like /data. If you're on EC2 you could use an EBS volume for this mount and easily upgrade it if you need more disk space later (copy it to a new volume and move that to the mount point)

Alternatively a lot of people use S3 to store files because it's cheap, you can get a url to the image and easily front it with amazon's CDN.

Comment: 10x for the answer. Most probably we will not have more than 10 GB of images

Comment: The key is to just put it on a volume outside of the web root and give the process access. I really like S3 for this too though.